How can I draw a slanted cone?
With a cone, I tried
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 1]},  Boxed -> False]


How can I draw this picture?


Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
   GeometricTransformation[Cone[], 
    ShearingTransform[xi, 
     RotationMatrix[fi, {0, 0, 1}] . {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]]}], {fi, 0,
   2 Pi}, {xi, 0, Pi/2}]




Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], 
  GeometricTransformation[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 1], 
   AffineTransform[{{1, 0, -.1}, {0, 1, -.2}, {0, 0, 1}}]]}]


reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   TransformedRegion[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 1], 
    Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} + {-.1 z, -.2 z, 0}]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[], reg}]


ScalingTransform along a direction.
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
  GeometricTransformation[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, 1], 
   ScalingTransform[2, {1, 1, 1}]]}, Boxed -> False]



This deforms the base also.

A  start (surfaces) :
c[p_, a_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[(1 - s) a {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + s p, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {s, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> p]

Some examples:
 Row[{c[{0, 0, 1}, 1],c[{1, 2, 3}, 1], c[{-1, 1, 3}, 2]}]


